# Brand new computer crashed during job interview - compensation?

Tags: compensation

My brand new computer cost me a job. The device crashed, not just once, but twice during a job interview over Skype. I took it back to the origin of purchase where it was diagnosed as a having software issues, it was subsequently wiped and the operating system was reinstalled fresh. The laptop was purchased two or three months ago. I'm curious as to whether there is any sort of  compensation available for situations like this? Of course, winning any sort of lawsuit against a large corporation is unlikely and nobody want's to set precedents taking responsibility for inability to procure work.

The exact cause of the crashes can be found here: [-20 shutdown, what to do?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/399894/115865)

Comment: So, you can prove categorically that the only reason you didn’t get the job was because your computer crashed? And not, say, because there was another candidate who might have been better than you?

Comment: @DaleM Proving it would be another hurdle. A computer crash during an interview for a remote position is surely detrimental though.

Comment: Really? Tech glitches happen all the time. You would need to prove that this particular cash caused you specific harm.

Comment: @DaleM yet surely we can consider the hypothetical case in which it *is* possible to prove that, however unlikely that might be, or even if we know that it is a contractual assumption for the sake of the analysis.  One reason to do this would be to determine whether it's worth going into the question of whether it's possible to prove: perhaps the computer manufacturer has no liability for the interview failure even if they were the sole cause of the failure.  If that's the case then we can save ourselves effort and anguish by just writing off the loss and moving on.

Comment: @phoog Well, you can take either approach can't you?  Show that causation can't be proved, or that liability is disclaimed, making the other point moot.  No one's voting to close here.

Comment: If the computer manufacturer was liable for this then you wouldn't be able to buy a computer.

Comment: I think you have a different definition of "exact cause" than I do. You say that the exact cause is listed on that other page, but I don't see it there; all I see is a log message and someone advising you to contact support to see what they recommend.

Comment: I think you should take the opposite approach. Get the report from the vendor stating that you presented a laptop, it showed to be faulty, etc. and repaired. Then contact with the company apologizing for the interview troubles and showing what you did. It may help or not. If the company still hasn't filled the position (there could be several weeks -or months- of interviews, and them still ongoing), and you wasn't already discarded from your failed interview, you might get another one to fill. (1/3)

Comment: That said, I don't think a company should reject a candidate just for a crashing computer. A user which showed a lack of technological ability (such as not being able to open a web page) could be considered a not-hire in the spot, but a computer failure, not so much. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if many of the interviews had glitches of one kind or other (perhaps not as bad as yours, but glitches anyway). (2/3)

Comment: The company should provide the equipment anyway, and make sure that it works properly with whatever software they expect you to use. Do note that it is possible that -even if they would otherwise still be interested in you- they already found stronger candidates in the interview process, and wouldn't be interested to engage you in the process again. (3/3)

Comment: Location? Different locations have different laws regarding consumer product warranties. In Australia, for instance, you'd be under the right to have faulty products repaired, replaced, or refunded, and the fact that they fixed the broken computer would fall under the first category.

Comment: @Ángel I think rejecting a candidate for this is entirely sensible if the candidate's job involves working with the computer.  It shows the candidate didn't think to prepare ahead of time and test the tools of their trade, or didn't know how to.

Comment: @AdamBarnes that's utterly ridiculous reasoning

Comment: @eps It's ridiculous to expect someone know how to use their tools, and to have made sure the ones they need for the interview are working ahead of time?

Comment: @AdamBarnes: Does there exist any individual on this earth who can certify that his laptop (ie. not fully manufactured by him regardless of who this person is) will not crash at a specified one-hour time period at some point over, for example, the coming week?

Comment: If the company did not let you schedule another interview (perhaps over the phone) then you probably don't want to work for them. I assume you telephoned them ASAP to explain the situation?

Comment: @AdamBarnes it does not mean that at all. If OP had agreed beforehand to show them their photoshop skills in a screenshare, you could blame him for not having installed photoshop in advance. But conferencing software? And moreover, using a system which would have been chosen by the interviewer, and the user may not have even been able to do a trial by himself ?

Comment: I have witnessed problems in conferences where that user the platform daily with the feature working perfectly (it turned out to be due to a maintenance from the provider, go prepare for that!). I have seen platforms where half participants in a meeting had issues. I have been in periodical conferences where it _always_ "needed" to update when you opened it. And then the day you tried to outsmart it by upgrading in advance the day before, that upgrade turning out to be buggy when talking, requiring you to... guess it, downgrade to the prior one.

Comment: "Two or three months ofd" - so it was already close to obsoletion?

Answer (score 25):

#### Almost certainly not

You note that "it was diagnosed as a having software issues," so you'd have to figure out exactly what software issue happened, and whose fault that was (assuming that it wasn't your fault).  This would be pretty difficult, especially given that they wiped the system.  Even assuming you have a backup copy and could figure out the exact problem, you probably also agreed to waive any such claims against the software authors that may have caused the problem when you received the software, because software companies don't want to pay for the consequences of every computer crash. Microsoft, for instance, requires you to agree that:

> Except for any repair, replacement, or refund that Microsoft, or the device manufacturer or installer, may provide, you may not under this limited warranty, under any other part of this agreement, or under any theory, recover any damages or other remedy, including lost profits or direct, consequential, special, indirect, or incidental damages. The damage exclusions and remedy limitations in this agreement apply even if repair, replacement, or a refund does not fully compensate you for any losses, if Microsoft, or the device manufacturer or installer, knew or should have known about the possibility of the damages, or if the remedy fails of its essential purpose.

Most software has similar disclaimers.  Stack Overflow has one, too, for instance.  So even if you did somehow track down exactly which piece of software caused the crash, you probably already agreed that they aren't responsible for paying your damages.

Comment: plus, Palsgraf v LIRC

Comment: I expect that the hardware warranty also disclaims consequential damages.  But terms of license agreements and warranties are not always valid at face value: there could be some statutory provision or legal precedent that allows a claim of consequential damages nonetheless.

Comment: @RyanM I don't know if we want to go down this rabbithole but I've updated my question with a link to the exact cause.

Comment: Not just software, but almost all products have such a clause.  Otherwise, ridiculous lawsuits would pop up like a Gucci handbag breaking and a $20k bottle of wine falling out and being broken - obviously Gucci will replace the handbag, but they're not replacing your bottle of wine.

Comment: Or ore on topic and pre-covid: "My car broke down on the way to an interview and caused me to lose the job" or "My alarm clock broke and..." or "My power was own and..." or anything else.  None of these manufacturers (or the power company) can be held liable for your lost job.

Comment: With respect to software and hardware, such warranties can be offered in some cases. Best example that comes to mind is a regulated industry where a software vendor makes a claim about compliance of it's software, or a medical device which uses components sold for medical use because they come with certificate of conformance per batch . Consumer and most industrial products do carry a limited liability, but there are situations where a supplier takes on a stricter liability, for a premium.